# HashSet & List for storing Strings

Tags: c#

Good night,

I was trying to benchmark the performance of HashSet and List datatypes in C# to check which one performs best when a lot of insertions/deletes need to be done. The code I am using is roughly the following.

```
public static Func<String, HashSet<String>> ListaPossiveisCorreccoes = StrPalavra => {

        (...)
        HashSet<String> ListaCorreccoes = new HashSet<String> ();
        (...)

        (Lots of .Add operations)

        return ListaCorreccoes;

    };


    public static Func<String, IEnumerable<String>> ListaCorreccoes = (StrPalavra) =>
    {


        HashSet<String> ConjuntoCorreccoes = new HashSet<String> ( );

        foreach (String StrTmp in ListaPossiveisCorreccoes(StrPalavra))
            foreach (String StrTmp2 in ListaPossiveisCorreccoes(StrTmp))
                ConjuntoCorreccoes.Add(StrTmp2);

        return ConjuntoCorreccoes/*.Distinct()*/.Where(PalavraConhecida)*/;

    };
```

When I run sequentaly the two functions outlined above it takes about 250-285ms to complete (I am using memoization). However, if I replace `HashSet<String>` with `List<String>` everywhere and uncomment the commented part of the last line (thus forcing duplicates to be removed from the list) it takes only 140-145ms to complete. This contradicts what I read about HashSets, which says that their performance is much better than that of lists in addition/removal operations. Can someone please tell me if this is normal? 250ms isn't of course much, but it is almost twice the time taken with lists, and that is important since these functions are intended to be called repeatedly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question

> This contradicts what I read about
>   HashSets, which says that their
>   performance is much better than that
>   of lists in **addition**/removal
>   operations

I'm not sure where you read that `HashSet<T>` has faster performance as compared to `Lis<T>` with respect to Add.  This is just simply wrong.

`List<T>.Add` in particular will outperform `HashSet<T>.Add`.  In the majority of cases Add on `List<T>` is simply an assignment into an array index and an increment of the index.  It's much more complicated for `HashSet<T>`.

Remove is more complex and depends a lot on whether elements are being removed from the begininig, end or middle of the collection.

Comment: This is where I took this idea from... http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/02/22/An-Overview-Of-System_Collections_Generic.aspx

Comment: You're right it will probably be slower than a List, but speaking in terms of order notation, the List and HashSet add operations are equivalent [O(1) in most cases]. MSDN says (for both List and HashSet):

If Count already equals the capacity of the HashSet<T> object, the capacity is automatically adjusted to accommodate the new item.

If Count is less than the capacity of the internal array, this method is an O(1) operation. If the HashSet<T> object must be resized, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This isn't mine but does have some interesting info.

http://www.phase9studios.com/post/2008/01/08/DictionaryVSHashTable.aspx

I always thought a hashtable was more for looking up values.  You get a performance boost in the lookup not the insert.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this interesting information, but in fact a dictionary is not suitable for the kind of task I need to do here... Anyway, I really appreciate your help.